# Why Does My Array Populate on Rebuild But Not on Page Refresh?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, fetch

I am using Vue 3 with Composition API, a Pinia store, TypeScript, SQL backend and Fetch to grab the data via my .NET 6 API.

I have a User.ts class

```
export default class User
{
    userName: string | null
    
    constructor (userName: string | null)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

and I Fetch the data from the DB using the below method

```
      getAdminUsers(): void
      {    
        fetch(apiURL + 'AdminUser',
        {
          headers:
          {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(response => 
          {
            return response.json();
          })
        .then(data =>
          { 
            this.$patch((state) =>
            {
              state.adminUser = { userName: null};
              state.adminUsers = [];
            })

            data.forEach((user: User) =>
            {
              if (user.userName)
              {
                this.adminUser = new User(user.userName.toUpperCase());
                this.adminUsers.push(this.adminUser);
              }
            })
          })
      },
```

For all the other data in my app, I have had no issues. However, when I refresh the page, or try run the getAdminUsers method from anywhere in my Vue app, it returns an empty array.

```
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

But when I make a tiny change to my app (such as add a space anywhere etc) and save>rebuild, the array is then populated with the correct data.

```
Proxy {0: User, 1: User}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(2)
0: User {userName: 'GEORGE.SMITHSON'}
1: User {userName: 'TEST.2'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

I really don't understand why it is happening and can't get it to work correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say since you do not include how you're using the array.  It definitely sounds as if your array is not reactive for some reason. That would explain why the array is not updating until a hot reload occurs.  Are you perhaps assigning it to another variable?  Is that variable also reactive?  If you are assigning it should be something like this:

```js
const adminStore = useAdminStore();
const adminUsers = computed(() => adminStore.adminUsers);
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!

So in my store I had: adminUsers: ref([]) as Ref<User[]> 

Then in whichever component I wanted to access, I was trying to log store.adminUsers or in the template {{store.adminUsers}} which worked until page reload. 

I was trying to access the value directly from the store, rather than assigning to a new variable, so in my component I now have adminUsers = store.adminUsers and it works

Are you please able to explain why, or provide resources that may help me understand why this happened and why I should do it your way, rather than my original way?